# How to find who is corrupting stack in c (linux) without using gdb?

Tags: c, linux, memory, stack

I am running a multiprocess app which always crashes at a function, but i could see the stack of that function has been corrupted, it is getting corrupted just when it returns from a function call inside that function. But when i tried to print where the parent functions stack getting changed inside the called function it does not change anywhere inside the called function but it changes immediately after it returns from the called function. Any idea why the stack getting corrupted only when it returns from the function ?.
Since i am running on a target mips box i tried to see who is writing to that stack using the address break point via gbdserver. But there is some problem with gdbserver it does not track the child process which is what i am interested in. Any idea how we can catch who is corrupting the stack in any other way ?

Comment: Did you try to run your application on a desktop x86 Linux system?

Comment: it is an mips embedded application needs certain hardware support so can't run on normal x86 system.

Comment: 0) add asserts for every index / pointer calculation 1) Divide & conquer : replace function bodies by empty bodies and see if the bug disappears. 2) the same for allocations : silently allocate more memory than you need; and oversize fixed arrays. 3) unit test every function or set of functions.

Comment: you could be handing out a pointer to a stack object that goes out of scope... while still in use... or using an inappropriate `alloca`

Comment: Perhaps a recent GCC might support `-fsanitize=address` on your MIPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). It shows you invalid reads/writes to memory and where are they.

Comment: I am already using valgrind but it show only stack shift is happening when the call returns but when the corruption has happened is not showing. I think valgrind is not tracking stack memory.

Comment: If you show the code for the function call, the called function, and the function prototypes, and the return statement(s) then we would have a chance of debugging the problem. My suspicion is there is a mismatch between the prototypes, the function declarations, the function call statement, and the return statement(s)

Comment: I moved to different box where i could not see this stack corruption any more. But using valgrind was useful atleast to show there is some problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the memory allocated in the function. There is a quite possibility of buffer overflow. When a function is returning then it will deallocate all the memory and if there is any illegal memory over-write then there is a possibility of crash.